# Facebook abnormal redirect

Tags: facebook, url, redirect

I have this page hosted on my web site

http://mihirsathe.com/mihir/Route

which opens normally when this link is copy-pasted into the navigation bar. But when I shared this link on Facebook, upon clicking on the shared link, I am taken stangely to another domain and it shows

`http://qimulta.ru/upday/index.php`

The domain is anyway inaccessible.
I know this is not exactly a programming question. But considering that I am showing bing maps on the above page, I suspect whether the problem is caused by it?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried it and it works correct.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander Nenkov said, the link works correctly.

I suspect the redirect may be done by a malware that has infected your website (or computer), since [entering **qimulta.ru** in Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=qimulta.ru&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) shows some results associated with malware listing/security sites (like [this one](http://sucuri.net/global)). Check your server (especially for the presence of hidden .htaccess files, since it seems this is the case).

Comment: But my web site is hosted by brinkster. Any chances they might have been affected?

Comment: It is definitely possible, it is sufficient for a small configuration bug to exist either in your site only or on their servers for bugs to be exploited.